# Finding Image Height variable for multiple images in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on this script for "tooltips" on a website. I'm finding that the code I currently have will get the image height for my first tooltip image on the page ('pop1') but it ignores the rest (they come out as null).

What's the most effective way to get all the tooltip image heights, and use them every time the user scrolls over the tooltip image?

Another issue, if anyone is able to figure this one out - is that on my FULL webpage (many more divs, rows, columns, etc.) the script begins to break because clientX and clientY are being affected by the various divs and page elements.

I'd like to be able to set clientX and clientY to the exact (x, y) coordinates that the user's mouse is at, relative to the entire webpage, not relative to the page's child elements.

Thanks

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgs7px4f/18/

JS Code:

```
$('a.popper').hover(function (e) {

    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    $(target).show();
}, function () {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    if (!($("a.popper").hasClass("show"))) {
        $(target).hide();
    }
});

$('a.popper').mousemove(function (e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    // images vary in height!
    // images are all 366px wide.
    var imageWidth = 366;
    var imageHeight = $(".popimg").height();
    //alert('Image Height: ' + imageHeight);

    //Offset tooltip:
    //10px to the right of cursor
    var imageX = e.clientX + 20;
    //imageHeight up from cursor
    var imageY = e.clientY - imageHeight - 20;

    // Find bounds of current window, and if...
    // Tooltip goes off right side:
    if ((imageX + imageWidth) > $(window).width()) {
        //Move tooltip left so it meets edge:
        imageX = $(window).width() - imageWidth;
    }
    // Tooltip goes off top
    if (imageY < 0) {
        //Move tooltip down so it meets top:
        imageY = 0;
    }
    $(target).css('top', imageY).css('left', imageX);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*What's the most effective way to get all the tooltip image heights, and use them every time the user scrolls over the tooltip image?*

First of all, I suppose you mean whenever a user does a mouseover on one of the elements? However, this seems to work and it cashes the height of the image directly on the element and uses it the next time a mouseover occurs:

```
 $('a.popper').mousemove(function (e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    // images vary in height!
    // images are all 366px wide.
    var imageWidth = 366;
    $target = $(target);

    if (!$target.attr("height")) {
        var img = $target.closest(".popbox").children("img");
        var imageHeight = img.height();
        $target.attr("height", imageHeight);
        console.log("height attribute set");
    } else {
        var imageHeight = +($target.attr("height")) + 0;
        console.log("cached height used");
    }

    console.log('Image Height: ', imageHeight);

    //Offset tooltip:
    //10px to the right of cursor
    var imageX = e.clientX + 20;
    //imageHeight up from cursor
    var imageY = e.clientY - imageHeight - 20;

    // Find bounds of current window, and if...
    // Tooltip goes off right side:
    if ((imageX + imageWidth) > $(window).width()) {
        //Move tooltip left so it meets edge:
        imageX = $(window).width() - imageWidth;
    }
    // Tooltip goes off top
    if (imageY < 0) {
        //Move tooltip down so it meets top:
        imageY = 0;
    }
    $(target).css('top', imageY).css('left', imageX);
});
```

Obviously, you should remove all the console.log statements which are for testing purposes only.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miqi180/Lcjc0yzo/)

Regarding your second question, it's hard to say anything concrete without another jsFiddle or additional code.